# Change deduplication interval in SQS FIFO

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Is there a way to increase `contentBasedDeduplication` interval in SQS FIFO Queues? In the [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) they mention

> If a message with a particular message deduplication ID is sent
>   successfully, any messages sent with the same message deduplication ID
>   are accepted successfully but aren't delivered during the 5-minute
>   deduplication interval.

However in the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html) they mention:

> When ContentBasedDeduplication is in effect, messages with identical
>   content sent within the deduplication interval are treated as
>   duplicates and only one copy of the message is delivered.

When I try to create a FIFO queue I do not see any option to change the deduplication interval. Is that fixed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In FIFO queues, the `Deduplication Interval` is fixed for 5 mins. Currently there is **NO** way to increase the deduplication time window.

This concern has been raised in one of the [AWS Forums in 2017](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=258650), but still it seems like this is not available as a feature.

**Additional Note**:

The purpose of having a `deduplication Interval` is to avoid processing the same message twice within the given 5 minutes. If you want to increase it, it would seem like an overhead on SQS because it needs to keep track of previous messages for a longer period.

I suggest having a filtering layer between your program and SQS, to remove duplicates, according to your required logic. Same with if you want to decrease it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way to implement a pattern so that the deduplication only occurs if an existing duplicate exists in the queue? I am wondering if you can make the producers check the queue for a duplicate message before publishing... but concerned that you could still end up with duplicates due to race conditions, and I'm also curious why AWS don't offer this as a native feature?

Answer (score 3):

There are no ways to change the deduplication time.
Deduplication will monitor the message even if it is deleted from the queue.
For FIFO queues, the Deduplication Interval is fixed for 5 mins.